# How to push form values to database in Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am building a drupal site in which I would like the admin to have the ability to input goals into a table on the drupal database that can then be output to other users to be completed.

The form for the input and the table get created, however the values are not added into the table when submit is pressed and I'm not sure why.

I have the following code from the module that I am hooking into my site. I think the problem occurs at the top where I am creating the fields, or at the bottom when I submit the values. I'm really not sure.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong and how to fix it?

```
<?php

function achievementList_init() {
if(!(db_table_exists('achievements'))) {
    $achvmnt_list_schema = array(
        'description' => 'Achievement Fields',
        'fields' => array (
            'achvmntID' => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'AUTO_INCREMENT' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE),

            'achvmntName' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 256, 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),

            'achvmntDesc' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 256, 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => ''),

            'achvmntPts' => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE),

    ));
    db_create_table('achievements', $achvmnt_list_schema);
}
}

function achievementList_menu($form, &$form_state) {
$items = array();
$items['achievementList/addAchievement'] = array(
    'title' => 'Achievement Input',
    'description' => 'Input Achievement info to add achievement to database',
    'page callback' =>'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('achievementList_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
);
return $items;
}

function achievementList_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['name'] = array (
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Achievement Name',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#maxlength' => '20',
    '#required' => TRUE
);
$form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Achievement Description',
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxLength' => 400,
    '#required' => TRUE

);
$form['points'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Point Award',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#maxlength' => '20',
    '#required' => TRUE
);
$form['add_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add Achievement')
);
return $form;
}

function achievementList_validate($form, &$form_state) {
$name = $form_state['values']['name'];

if($form_state['values']['name'] = '') {
    form_set_error('name', t('Achievement must have a name!'));
}
if($form_state['values']['description'] = '') {
    form_set_error('name', t('Please describe the achievement!'));
}
if(!($form_state['values']['points'] > 0)) {
    form_set_error('name', t('Achievement must be worth points!'));
}
}

function achievementList_submit($form, &$form_state) {
db_insert('achievements')
->fields(array(
'achvmntName' => $form_state['values']['name'],
'achvmntDesc' => $form_state['values']['description'],
'achvmntPts' => $form_state['values']['points'],
))
->execute();
}
```

Comment: As @Prashant Kanse stated it's better to use hook_schema in a module.install file. Still either way your table gets created. However you're calling the wrong hooks for validation & submit. `achievementList_validate($form, &$form_state)` should be `achievementList_form_validate($form, &$form_state)` & the submit hook should be `achievementList_form_submit($form, &$form_state)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should add SQL Table creation code under [HOOK_SCHEMA](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) in ".install" file.
- After you enable module confirm you table is created under mysql as
  per requirement.
- After that you code should work fine.[Remove SQL table creation code
  from HOOK_INIT]

You can refer [Drupal Example module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)

Cheers!!!